# About sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable: the name of the file is not retrieved when updating?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this form class:

```
class NewsItemForm extends BaseNewsItemForm
{
  public function configure()
  {

    $this->useFields(array('title', 'picture', 'text'));

    $this->widgetSchema['picture'] = new
sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(

      'file_src'  => '/uploads/'.$this->getObject()->getPicture(),
      'is_image'  => true,
      'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew(),
      'template'  => '<div>%file%<br />%input%<br />%delete%
%delete_label%</div>',
    ));

    $this->validatorSchema['picture'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
                          'mime_types' => 'web_images',
                          'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
                          'required' => true,
                          'validated_file_class' =>
'myValidatedResizedFile'));

  }

}
```

I submit the form correctly, after that, the same form is showed this
time to update the data submited, but the problem is it's not
retrieving the info about the picture, I mean, the picture is showed
but next to the "Browse.." button there is written "No file chosen",
in fact, if I try to submit the form I get the error message
"Required" for the picture field.

Any idea?

sf 1.4.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  **'required' => $this->isNew()**:

```
 $this->validatorSchema['picture'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
                          'mime_types' => 'web_images',
                          'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
                          'required' => true,
                          'required' => $this->isNew(),
                          'validated_file_class' =>
'myValidatedResizedFile'));

  }
```